# Upload a file to specific folder in windows forms and upload file name to sql server

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application and it is written in C#.  I am also using a sql server with a datagridview.  I have an Add form in my program that allows a user to enter in data to a multiple of text boxes that uploads to my server.  I have this part completed and it works just great.

I have a textbox called 'resumelinkTextBox.' I also have a browse button that will open an 'open file dialog.'  I want to be able to select a file from the open file dialog browser, which in turn will enter the path into the 'resumelinkTextBox.'  When I hit 'Add resume,' I want it to upload the file to a specified folder on my network.  Also, I need it to update the 'resumelink' column in my sql server, but with ONLY the name of the file.  So if my file is located at "C:\Users\newresume.doc" I need that to upload to "C:\Users\NewResumes" and then have just the filename 'newresume.doc' in the 'resumelink' column of my sql server.

Any examples or links to examples would be greatly appreciated.

Below here is my insert command that uploads information from the textboxes to my sql server.

```
insertCommand.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT HRResume ON; INSERT INTO HRresume (name, skillset, recordkey, date, comment, referral, resumelink) VALUES (@name, @skillset, @recordkey, @date, @comment, @referral, @resumelink); SET IDENTITY_INSERT HRResume OFF";
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@skillset", skillsetTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recordkey", recordkeyTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", commentTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referral", referralTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resumelink", resumelinkTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Connection.Open();
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Resume Added.");
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general question. Use `File.OpenRead()` and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx

and then parse the file path and get its name and do sql insert like you did before.